# How to initialize ember.js manually to inject my own DS Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I noticed in the current version of master you no longer need to initialize your ember app (it seems to just happen on load).

But because I want to unit test parts of my ember app I'd like to know how I could add a store manually.

```
initialize: function(container, application) {
     container.register('store', 'main', application.Store);    
     container.lookup('store:main');    
}
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/708acf8cbfb31abe0accf0e8461069fa5785fc63

In the commit listed above it looks like I just need to add a default store. What is the default container and how can I invoke these 2 lines myself when I need to mock / inject a store?